# Correcto uso de la app admin de django

Tags: python, django

Cual es el correcto uso que se le debe dar a la página de administración (django.contrib.admin) **en una aplicación en producción**. explico mi pregunta.

El sitio de administración permite gestionar los modelos creado de una forma bastante simple y abstracta por lo que para alguien nuevo es bastante seductor crear un sistema *( no se por ejemplo un sistema de gestión médica )* crear modelos de doctor, citas, enfermeras etc, etc, etc. y al terminar registrar todos estos en el "admin site" y hacer que el uso del sistema sea mediante el. y que todos los usuarios ( secretarias, doctores etc, etc, etc ) entren al **admin site** con los permisos específicos para editar ciertos modelos.

Ahora en la documentación dice:

> One of the most powerful parts of Django is the automatic admin interface. It reads metadata from your models to provide a quick, model-centric interface **where trusted users can manage content on your site**. The admin’s recommended use is limited to an organization’s internal management tool. It’s not intended for building your entire front end around.

Lo que deja claro que no debe ser usada como solución frontend para los clientes. pero Lo que quiero aclarar es como seria la manera correcta de para un sistema ya en producción.

#### Cual sería su lugar en la arquitectura del sistema y su principal modo de uso.

Imaginamos que existe un completo frontend para mi sistema.

Comment: Muchas buenas preguntas generan cierto grado de opinión según la experiencia de los expertos, pero casi todas las respuestas a esta pregunta estarán basadas en opiniones, en lugar de hechos, referencias o experiencia específica. PD. La aplicación `admin` es altamente configuraba y se puede extender de acuerdo a las necesidades y competencias de cada uno.

Answer (score 2):

Según mi experiencia, el admin de Django está enfocado en los administradores directos, te pongo el siguiente ejemplo:

Una web de noticias como [esta](http://www.seguimiento.co/) donde los editores son miembros selectos de la web y los usuarios finales son los que consumen el contenido, aqui el admin de Django calza perfectamente donde podemos resaltar los siguientes roles:

- El superadmin que crea los usuarios editores y edita los permisos.
- Los editores que suben el contenido
- Los usuarios finales (registrados o anónimos) que consumen el contenido

Estos últimos no tendrían acceso al administrador de django.

Ahora imagina que cualquier persona puede registrarse y subir noticias, en ese caso el administrador de Django ya no seria buena idea, entonces te tocaría crear una aplicación aparte para este propósito para mejorar la experiencia de usuario (ya que es para el usuario del común) y quedaría de esta forma:

- El superadmin (Admin de Django)
- Los usuarios redactores (App propia)

En general, el admin de django en producción es mas para tareas administrativas(superusuarios) en donde los usuarios que ingresen tengan un mínimo de conocimiento de las reglas del negocio. Aunque el admin de Django puede parecerte sencillo y es muy personalizable, creeme que hay un punto donde no puedes editarlo mas (sobre todo cuando quieres filtrar información por roles de usuario) se vuelve inmanejable, es mas factible crear una aplicación nueva para esto y de paso hacer mejores en el diseño o incluso hacer una single page application usando angular o cualquier libreria de este tipo.

En el caso especifico de tu ejemplo, usuaria el admin de django para el dueño del negocio, el que registra usuarios administradores que agregar medicos, enfermeras, etc.. y una aplicación principal donde tenga los modulos de cada uno de esos usuarios y la gestion de citas.

Espero haberte ayudado.
Saludos.

Comment: me gusto tu explicación muchas gracias.